# In windows Java SecureRandom.generateSeed failed: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure

Tags: java, windows, random

In production environment(Windows 2008 R2, AMD 64, 8 GB RAM), the application sometimes throws the following exception - restart the application solves the problem.

```
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Unexpected CryptoAPI failure generating seed
at sun.security.provider.NativeSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(NativeSeedGenerator.java:43)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:117)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineGenerateSeed(SecureRandom.java:114)
at java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(SecureRandom.java:475)
```

The code should have no problem :

```
    public void generateToken ()
    {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        int seedByteCount = 20;
        byte[] seed = secureRandom.generateSeed(seedByteCount);
        secureRandom.setSeed(seed);
        String random = String.valueOf(secureRandom.nextLong());
        setToken(random);
    }
```

Took a look at JDK code, find out that the error is because `Java_sun_security_provider_NativeSeedGenerator_nativeGenerateSeed` returns **false** :

> openjdk-7u2-fcs-src-b13-17_nov_2011\jdk\src\windows\native\sun\security\provider\WinCAPISeedGenerator.c :

```
    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_sun_security_provider_NativeSeedGenerator_nativeGenerateSeed(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jbyteArray randArray)
    {
        HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
        jboolean result = JNI_FALSE;
        jsize numBytes;
        jbyte* randBytes;

        if (CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, "J2SE", NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0) == FALSE) {
            /* If CSP context hasn't been created, create one. */
            if (CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, "J2SE", NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL,
                    CRYPT_NEWKEYSET) == FALSE) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        numBytes = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, randArray);
        randBytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, randArray, NULL);
        if (CryptGenRandom(hCryptProv, numBytes, randBytes)) {
            result = JNI_TRUE;
        }
        (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, randArray, randBytes, 0);

        CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);

        return result;
    }
```

`CryptGenRandom` or `CryptAcquireContextA` returns **false**, but I don't know why it fails, and how to work around it.

Anyone knows why this happens, the work around or how to continue to investigate this problem?

Thanks for any advice or reply. Thanks...

Btw - I found the following resources - but not quite useful to this problem.

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2231037
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6202721
- [Proper use of Java’s SecureRandom](http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/)
- [Secure Random Number Generation in JAVA](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/random-number-generation-java/)

Comment: Take a look at answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667129/cryptacquirecontexta-fails-in-c-clr-for-aloaha-cryptographic-provider). Are race conditions possible in your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your problem smells like a concurrent access problem, I have a workaround for you: Use bouncycastle as a JCE provider and see if that fixes your problem. Put the jar into your classpath, then at some point run this code: `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes, as you said this is a concurrent access related problem, we optimize our code: in old code, we can generateSeed for each request, this is bad, as generateSeed consumes a lot of resource. In the new code, we only call generateSeed one time. This seems solved the problem customer met.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the generation of random number has a high resource consumption in terms of CPU cycles. If you have the possibility to minimize the number of calls to the java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed method, go ahead, that will definitely will help.

On the other hand, note that the seed generation is finally implemented by the security providers calling to native functions.

The list of SPs is located at JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security file, and by default, that sun.security.provider.Sun is on the top. If that guy is causing problems, it could be disabled, making sure the indexes are restructured as well.

For future references on how to disable a security provider from the java.security file: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Disable-pkcs11