# Cipher.getInstance() slow when called from multiple JVM instances on unix platforms

Tags: java, performance, java-security

I have an application that spawns multiple short-lived java (IBM Java 8) programs in which they need to make an SSL request to a server. I am running into an issue where if I run several instances of these in parallel they all take an equal amount, and much longer time to run. In some cases it saves almost no time as if I had run them serially. For example, if 1 instance takes 3 seconds to run, if I run 5 in parallel they might all take 15 seconds to run.

I have noticed that this does not seem to be an issue on Windows systems. I'm not very familiar with the Java security libraries, and I did find this post [Slow SecureRandom initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322948/slow-securerandom-initialization/49322949#49322949) which seems like it might be the root cause, but I was unable to get the code snippets to work for the `Cipher.getInstance()` call.

To demonstrate the problem, I have distilled it down to this code snippet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class CipherTesting {
    private static final int DEFAULT = 20;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        int num = parseArg( args );

        if ( num > 1 ) {
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool( num );
            List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++ ) {
                results.add( executor.submit( new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        String output = execute( "java", "-cp", System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ),
                            CipherTesting.class.getSimpleName(), "" + 1 );
                        return output;
                    }
                } ) );
            }
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination( 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
            List<Integer> times = new ArrayList<>( num );
            for ( Future<String> result : results ) {
                System.err.println( result.get() );
                times.add( Integer.parseInt( result.get().split( ":" )[1].trim() ) );
            }
            IntSummaryStatistics stats = times.stream().mapToInt( ( x ) -> x ).summaryStatistics();
            System.out.println( stats.toString() );
        } else {
            test();
        }
    }

    private static void test() {
        try {
            Provider provider = new com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlusFIPS();
            Security.insertProviderAt( provider, 1 );
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Cipher.getInstance( "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", provider.getClass().getSimpleName() );
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println( "JVM" + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().replaceAll( "@.+", "" )
                + " Time: " + ( end - start ) );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int parseArg( String[] args ) {
        if ( args.length == 0 ) {
            return DEFAULT;
        } else if ( args.length == 1 && args[0].trim().matches( "\\d+" ) ) {
            return Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
        } else {
            System.out.println( "first argument must be a number" );
            System.exit( 1 );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static String execute( String... commands ) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec( commands );

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( proc.getInputStream() ) );

        // Read the output from the command
        String s = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ( ( s = stdInput.readLine() ) != null ) {
            sb.append( s );
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to install IBM Java, I have tested this in the ibmjava docker container using the command:

```
λ  docker run -it --rm -v %CD%:/example ibmjava:8 java -cp /example/bin/ CipherTestingSimple 20
JVM76 Time: 15469
JVM77 Time: 17598
JVM80 Time: 15173
JVM55 Time: 14612
JVM78 Time: 16281
JVM58 Time: 17610
JVM49 Time: 17600
JVM48 Time: 16641
JVM75 Time: 16497
JVM54 Time: 19725
JVM59 Time: 16494
JVM61 Time: 17435
JVM56 Time: 18056
JVM73 Time: 16212
JVM81 Time: 18385
JVM74 Time: 17136
JVM60 Time: 17857
JVM57 Time: 17073
JVM72 Time: 16422
JVM79 Time: 15348
IntSummaryStatistics{count=20, sum=337624, min=14612, average=16881.200000, max=19725}
```

Vs on windows:

```
JVM5476 Time: 906
JVM34144 Time: 3576
JVM28468 Time: 2751
JVM36084 Time: 2741
JVM16700 Time: 2560
JVM8640 Time: 2454
JVM34112 Time: 3140
JVM33364 Time: 3362
JVM17132 Time: 3999
JVM14160 Time: 3683
JVM11816 Time: 933
JVM33252 Time: 2878
JVM13660 Time: 2315
JVM12068 Time: 2416
JVM24240 Time: 3218
JVM30032 Time: 2965
JVM32316 Time: 3081
JVM14436 Time: 4532
JVM12764 Time: 2793
JVM14692 Time: 962
IntSummaryStatistics{count=20, sum=55265, min=906, average=2763.250000, max=4532}
```

I have also noticed a similar issue with calls to `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket()` but am hopeful that the solution to this Cipher problem would also solve that.

Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit 1 05/04/2020**
@rustyx

```
root@9a230345867e:/# cat $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security | grep securerandom.source=
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

I also killed one of the child java processes (after waiting about 7 seconds) using the `-3` signal, which included the output:

```
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "user", detail "" at 2020/05/04 16:23:13 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '//javacore.20200504.162313.2812.0001.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to //javacore.20200504.162313.2812.0001.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "user", detail "".
```

The output from that javacore can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/UML6AL4s).

**Edit 2 05/04/2020**
I should note, the code used when creating the javacore had the following lines commented out. Did this during my testing the code on open java and forgot to undo it. Behavior is still the same, but figured should mention.

```
            Provider provider = new com.ibm.crypto.plus.provider.IBMJCEPlusFIPS();
            Security.insertProviderAt( provider, 1 );
```

Comment: What is your machine configuration? I have had issues with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` on EC2 instances where the machine had limited threads. It actually made the parallel processing slower than sequential processing. Another speculation, there also may be performance differences if you are using IBM Java8 vs Oracle Java licensed version.

Comment: I've been seeing this on a variety of systems. The system from which I posted the output was an i7-6820HQ with 64gb of ram. The Docker vm was allocated 4 cores, and 16gb. 

The thread pool does not seem like the culprit here, but it does seem to be related to the security provider with IBM Java. If I run the test using the default security Provider in the `java:8` docker image I see much better results: `{count=20, sum=14095, min=559, average=704.750000, max=795}` . If I use the default Provider with IBM Java, instead of `IBMJCEPlusFIPS` I see far worse results.

Comment: Do a thread dump (`kill -3`) halfway into those 15 s and edit the results into the question. Also please include the value of `securerandom.source` from java.security.

Comment: @rustyx I believe I have provided the information you requested, if I missed something please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBMJCEPlusFIPS is a U.S. export-controlled provider. Due to this, IBM JCE verifies the signatures of all bundled security JARs, in an attempt to enforce this.

If you take a few stacktrace samples of the main thread, you will see that it is indeed mainly busy verifying JAR files and a self-test (omitted here).

```
(sample) Java callstack:
    at java/nio/DirectByteBuffer$Deallocator.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:72)
    at java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:139)
    at java/nio/ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/icc/FastJNIBuffer.<init>(FastJNIBuffer.java:24)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/icc/FastJNIBuffer.create(FastJNIBuffer.java:5)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/icc/Digest.<clinit>(Digest.java:129)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/icc/Signature.<init>(Signature.java:16)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/icc/Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:3)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/s.<init>(s.java:20)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/DSASignature$SHA1withDSA.<init>(DSASignature.java:1)
    at sun/reflect/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun/reflect/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at sun/reflect/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java/lang/reflect/Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com/ibm/crypto/plus/provider/r.newInstance(r.java:8)
    at java/security/Signature.isSpi(Signature.java:297)
    at java/security/Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:240)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:702)
       (entered lock: com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertImpl@0x00000000FFF3DE78, entry count: 1)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:623)
    at javax/crypto/b.a(Bytecode PC:80)
    at javax/crypto/b.access$500(Bytecode PC:1)
    at javax/crypto/b$a.run(Bytecode PC:88)
    at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:734)
    at javax/crypto/b.<clinit>(Bytecode PC:1211)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:93)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:73)
    at Test.test(Test.java:56)
    at Test.main(Test.java:47)

(sample) Java callstack:
    at com/ibm/security/bootstrap/InternalSHA.update(InternalSHA.java:128)
    at com/ibm/security/bootstrap/DSASignature.engineUpdate(DSASignature.java:274)
    at java/security/Signature.update(Signature.java:770)
    at java/security/Signature.update(Signature.java:743)
    at sun/security/pkcs/SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:516)
    at sun/security/pkcs/PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:592)
    at sun/security/pkcs/PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:609)
    at sun/security/util/SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:297)
    at sun/security/util/SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:273)
    at java/util/jar/JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:329(Compiled Code))
    at java/util/jar/JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:241(Compiled Code))
    at java/util/jar/JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:459)
    at java/util/jar/JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:526)
       (entered lock: sun/net/www/protocol/jar/URLJarFile@0x00000000FFEF0438, entry count: 1)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:165)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:23)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:28)
    at javax/crypto/b.b(Bytecode PC:14)
    at javax/crypto/b.a(Bytecode PC:79)
       (entered lock: javax/crypto/b@0x00000000E0179208, entry count: 1)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:93)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:73)
    at Test.test(Test.java:56)
    at Test.main(Test.java:47)

(sample) Java callstack:
    at java/lang/StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:450)
       (entered lock: java/lang/StringBuffer@0x00000000FFDF5068, entry count: 1)
    at com/ibm/security/util/ObjectIdentifier.toString(ObjectIdentifier.java:479)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/AVAKeyword.getKeyword(AVA.java:2093)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/AVA.toKeyword(AVA.java:1092)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/AVA.toString(AVA.java:1146)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/RDN.toString(RDN.java:450)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X500Name.generateDN(X500Name.java:1231(Compiled Code))
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X500Name.toString(X500Name.java:775)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:986)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:240)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:2714)
    at com/ibm/security/x509/X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:231)
    at com/ibm/crypto/provider/X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Bytecode PC:91)
    at java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:350)
    at com/ibm/crypto/provider/JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Bytecode PC:585)
       (entered lock: java/util/Hashtable@0x00000000FFCC9900, entry count: 1)
    at java/security/KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1456)
    at com/ibm/security/util/AnchorCertificates$1.run(AnchorCertificates.java:58)
    at com/ibm/security/util/AnchorCertificates$1.run(AnchorCertificates.java:49)
    at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
    at com/ibm/security/util/AnchorCertificates.<clinit>(AnchorCertificates.java:49)
    at com/ibm/security/cert/AlgorithmChecker.checkFingerprint(AlgorithmChecker.java:233)
    at com/ibm/security/cert/AlgorithmChecker.<init>(AlgorithmChecker.java:174)
    at com/ibm/security/cert/AlgorithmChecker.<init>(AlgorithmChecker.java:114)
    at com/ibm/security/validator/SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:151)
    at com/ibm/security/validator/Validator.validate(Validator.java:257)
    at com/ibm/security/validator/Validator.validate(Validator.java:233)
    at com/ibm/security/validator/Validator.validate(Validator.java:202)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:5)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:451)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:23)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:28)
    at javax/crypto/b.b(Bytecode PC:14)
    at javax/crypto/b.a(Bytecode PC:79)
       (entered lock: javax/crypto/b@0x00000000E0179208, entry count: 1)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:93)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:73)
    at Test.test(Test.java:56)
    at Test.main(Test.java:47)

(sample) Java callstack:
    at java/util/ArrayDeque.add(ArrayDeque.java:434)
    at java/util/zip/ZipFile.releaseInflater(ZipFile.java:533)
       (entered lock: java/util/ArrayDeque@0x00000000E0150D08, entry count: 1)
    at java/util/zip/ZipFile.access$100(ZipFile.java:76)
    at java/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.close(ZipFile.java:473)
    at java/util/jar/JarVerifier$VerifierStream.close(JarVerifier.java:506)
    at java/io/BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:494)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:193)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:23)
    at javax/crypto/a.a(Bytecode PC:28)
    at javax/crypto/b.b(Bytecode PC:14)
    at javax/crypto/b.a(Bytecode PC:79)
       (entered lock: javax/crypto/b@0x00000000E00FC1E8, entry count: 1)
    at javax/crypto/b.b(Bytecode PC:1)
    at javax/crypto/Cipher.getInstance(Bytecode PC:117)
    at CipherTesting.test(CipherTesting.java:77)
    at CipherTesting.main(CipherTesting.java:56)

(sample) Java callstack:
    at java/math/Division.modInverseMontgomery(Division.java:547)
    at java/math/BigInteger.modInverse(BigInteger.java:1352)
    at com/ibm/security/bootstrap/DSASignature.generateW(DSASignature.java:202)
    at com/ibm/security/bootstrap/DSASignature.engineVerify(DSASignature.java:170)
    at java/security/Signature.verify(Signature.java:661)
    at sun/security/pkcs/SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:517)
    at sun/security/pkcs/PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:592)
    at sun/security/pkcs/PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:609)
    at sun/security/util/SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:297)
    at sun/security/util/SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:273)
    at java/util/jar/JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:329)
    at java/util/jar/JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:241(Compiled Code))
    at java/util/jar/JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:459)
    at java/util/jar/JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:708)
       (entered lock: java/util/jar/JarFile@0x00000000E004B5E0, entry count: 1)
    at java/util/jar/JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:80)
    at sun/misc/URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:1121)
    at java/net/URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:689)
    at java/net/URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:96)
    at java/net/URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1187)
    at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
    at java/net/URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:605)
    at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:944)
       (entered lock: java/lang/ClassLoader$ClassNameBasedLock@0x00000000E00DA6B0, entry count: 1)
    at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:933)
       (entered lock: java/lang/ClassLoader$ClassNameBasedLock@0x00000000E00DA6C0, entry count: 1)
    at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:889)
    at sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:227)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:218)
    at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:678)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:218)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:199)
       (entered lock: sun/security/jca/ProviderConfig@0x00000000E00716F0, entry count: 1)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderList.loadAll(ProviderList.java:294)
    at sun/security/jca/ProviderList.removeInvalid(ProviderList.java:311)
    at sun/security/jca/Providers.getFullProviderList(Providers.java:181)
    at java/security/Security.insertProviderAt(Security.java:371)
       (entered lock: java/security/Security@0x00000000E0019898, entry count: 1)
    at Test.test(Test.java:54)
    at Test.main(Test.java:47)
```

IBM JCE seems to be hard-coded to perform these checks and the classes are obfuscated, so bypassing it would not be straightforward.

If filesystem I/O is the bottleneck (which is definitely the case on Windows, let alone a VM running inside Windows), then you will see progressively worse performance from parallel execution.

You could try OpenJDK with a provider like BouncyCastle as a possible alternative.

But in general, Java VM startup is slow and this is another example of why you should prefer to start a JVM once and re-use it as much as possible.

---

If you want to investigate this further, use a profiler or this poor-mans profiler to see what the thread under test is busy with.

```
    final Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    final String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().replaceFirst("@.*", "");
    Thread dumper = new Thread(() -> {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
        for (int i = 0, step = 50; ; i += step) {
            try { Thread.sleep(step); } catch (InterruptedException e) { break; }
            sb.setLength(0);
            for (StackTraceElement e : t.getStackTrace()) {
                sb.append("  ").append(e).append("\n");
            }
            System.out.print(pid + " @" + i + "ms: [" + t.getName() + "]:\n" + sb);
        }
    });
    dumper.start();
    test(); // <-- work to be profiled goes here
    dumper.interrupt();
```

Comment: Very interesting! I was collecting more dumps (which I can still send if you'd like) at various intervals, but digging through them I see similar stacks. I do agree that re-using a JVM would be preferable but the nature of the application I'm working with eliminates that as an option. 

However, I see cpu being the main bottleneck here and not the filesystem I/O. So 2 questions. Would this still be from just from the locking/extracting involved in verifying the jar files? And 2, any ideas why I do not see the issue running on my windows host, also with IBM Java? Just for my own information.

Comment: It should be the same, except Docker on Windows has high overhead, both I/O and CPU. Make sure to give the Docker VM max CPU and more RAM.

Comment: I gave docker all 8 cores and there was still no improvement. But that's ok, I'll attribute that to the overhead of docker on windows in general as you've said. I tested this out on a much more powerful system and sure enough it was much faster, so looks like you have correctly diagnosed the problem. Thank you very much again! I was looking in the completely wrong place for this problem, and I'm not sure I would ever have been able to correctly diagnose this one.